# For a continuous function defined on [a,b] , is the set of points at which f(x)>d closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, semicontinuous-functions

Prove that if f(x) is a continuous function defined on [a,b] , then the set of points at which $f(x) \geq d$ is closed, for all numbers d.

Comment: Consider $[a,b]=[0,1], f(x)=x^2$ and $d=0$ . Then the set is not closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake, f(x) is equal and greater than for all d numbers

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?  What is your definition of a "closed set"; do you use sequences or open complements?

Answer (score 1):

The general topology definition of a continuous function $f$ says that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed for any closed $F$. Is a set $[d,\infty)$ closed?